# filter realization help

Tags: digital-logic, filter

I need a help with filter realization. I dont understand how this works. This is a multiply and accumulate filter, I dont understand why cof[0] constant is multiplied, here is the code cof is the filter coefficients and sample is the samples. Any help with this very appreciated. Thank you

```
long long mac(int len, int *sample, int *cof, int item)
{
   int i, io;
   static long long y;

   io = 0;
   y = 0;
   item /= 4;
   for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
      {
      y += (long long)sample[io] * (long long)cof[0];
      cof +=item;
      io++;
      if ( io >= len )
         io = 0;
      }
   return y;
}
```

Comment: This *may* be a decimating filter; note the line `cof +=item;` - this is modifying the *pointer* so it is now pointing at a different location (dependent on the value of `item` which is not explained). So multiplying by `cof[0]` is not necessarily multiplying by the same value each time through the loop. The `item /=4;` is probably to convert to word values from byte values.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is a decimating filter. Thank you very much about the explanation about cof[0].It is clear for me. I have a another question why "item /= 4" is divded by 4?

Comment: I have converted this to answer including the division by 4.

Answer (score 1):

[Converted to an answer]

This looks like a [decimating](https://dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/multirate/decimation/) filter (probably part of an FIR); note the line `cof +=item;` - this is modifying the *pointer* so it is now pointing at a different location (dependent on the value of item which appears to be the decimation factor). `item` appears to be the decimation interval in *bytes*.

So multiplying by `cof[0]` is not multiplying by the same value each time through the loop.

The `item /=4;` changes byte interval addresses to word interval addresses as this looks like it is a 32 bit machine and the division by 4 is why I believe the `item` interval is in bytes. It would actually be far more portable if the code used the `sizeof()` operator but that is a minor nit.

In addition, there would need to be a check that `item %4 == 0;` somewhere

Comment: Thank you Peter Smith, I made a mistake posting another question, this is also part of the code and this is related. Would you able to check this.https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/499159/filter-realisation-help?noredirect=1#comment1272193_499159